# Can't get my page number in TOC match the report?

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm trying to create the table of contents for my report, I'm able to produce the table of contents(TOC) however I can't seem to get the page numbers in the TOC to match the page numbers in my report. Here is my code, what am I doing wrong ??
 [image: My TOC looks something like this]

```
\section*{Abstract}
\pagestyle{empty}
in this project we will.....
\newpage

\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{plain}

\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}


\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of figures}
\newpage

\section*{List of symbol} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of symbols}
\newpage

\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Introduction}\label{sec:intro}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please make your code snippet compilable? You can use a package like `lipsum` or `blindtext` to generate dummy text if needed ...

Comment: Thanks that helped !! I'm a total newbie to latex... I was able to get my page numbers to match in the dummy text.... so why do u think I'm not able to produce the same in my original document?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
```

use

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
\tableofcontents
```

Your current use seems to print the ToC entry too late. Switching them around should work provided you don't print any content between your `\newpage` and `\tableofcontents`.